# Calling multithreaded methods in one class

Tags: java, multithreading, inner-classes

My Java program has a class with two methods which will be called by threads. How can I start two threads, one calling one method and the second thread calling the other method? Should I use two inner classes, each implementing the Runnable interface or something else?

```
public class Example {
    public void read(String key) { /* some code */ }
    public void write(String key, InputStream inputStream) { /* some code */}
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with posted code regarding multithreading?

Comment: Unclear; you say that they "must work in multithreading"; I understand this as "there is a synchronization point"; what is this synchronization point?

Comment: It depends on states (variables) that your instance are going to have. For now your code will be thread safe because it is "Stateless"

Comment: How should I start this methods in mutithreaded way? Runnable interface doesn't allow create run method for read and run method for write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the code inside the methods. But if they are really just writes and reads to some resource, then reads can be performed in parallel without causing problems (since you are only reading). But for writes it is different. Only one thread at a time is allowed to write the same resource and no other thread can read or write it in the meantime (mutual exclusion). You could have a look at [this tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/read-write-locks.html) about Read / Write locks, which nicely represents the idea of sharing a lock for reads and handling writes to maintain consistency.

**Edit after rewriting the question**: Start 2 threads, each calling one method:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        write(..);
    }
});
Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        read(..);
    }
});
t1.start();
t2.start();
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This problem I probably solved. My problem is that i don't know how properly start these methods in different threads as i can't make two run methods if class Example implements Runnable.

Comment: Ah, I've missed that you've edited the question in the meantime. So you want that each thread starts one method?

Comment: Yep, each thread must starts with only one of the methods.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want to do something like this? (see my edit)

Answer (score 0):

You can mark both methods as synchronized.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/synchronized.html